# Order Types, Point-line duality

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am trying to understand Order Types and their enumeration.

I'm having a real hard time understanding these slides.. Especially the one I am showing. Could anyone explain to me what this slide from [this pdf](http://www.ist.tugraz.at/aichholzer/teaching/eca/03_ORDER_TYPES_HANDOUT.pdf) is describing? And maybe there is anybody who can explain to me what exactly I am studying here .. It came up in one class in which I couldn't attend and after staring a few hours at those slides I still have no clue what exactly they want from me.

I'm sorry I know his is a "please explain everything to me" kind of question but this problem doesn't seem to be googleable ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is common to map a point (a, b) to another point, by perhaps a translation, a rotation or a reflection. One can also map points to lines and it might be done in different ways. For example, this is illustrated here - several different point to line "dualities": http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.838/S98/meetings/m3/duality.htm
(scroll down to the bottom). In the graphic you show what I think is being described is a "matrix multiplication" to map a point given by a coordinate pair to a line given by an equation.